# Android Espresso: How do I add my own log output when a test fails?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have this array of values that are considered wrong

```
 public static final String[] WRONG_VALUES = {"1000","4000","2000"};
```

In my test I am clicking on the edit text, inserting the text and pressing back to close the keyboard.

```
  onView(withId(R.id.inputField)).perform(click(), replaceText(text), pressBack());
```

and then check if the error view is showing

```
onView(withId(R.id.error)).matches(not(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
```

This is working but I would like output somewhere in the test log the value which it failed for because when the test does fail I do not know which value was being tested
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details about problem, are you just asking how to log any value in Android?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can implement the `FailureHandler` interface to define custom failure handling for Espresso:

```
public class CustomFailureHandler implements FailureHandler {

    private final FailureHandler delegate;

    public CustomFailureHandler(@NonNull Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        delegate = new DefaultFailureHandler(instrumentation.getTargetContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final Throwable error, final Matcher<View> viewMatcher) {            
        // Log anything you want here

        // Then delegate the error handling to the default handler which will throw an exception
        delegate.handle(error, viewMatcher);          
    }
}
```

Before your tests are running, create and set the custom error handler like this:

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
Espresso.setFailureHandler(new CustomFailureHandler(instrumentation));
```

Comment: This almost worked for me (no code errors) but then I end up with the dreaded No static method forceEnableAppTracing()V error.

Answer (score 0):

You can even log your custom messages for particular assertions by catching their `Exception` and throwing your own instead like:

```
try {
    onView().check() // Some test here
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new Exception("This test failed with this custom message logged: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work in cases where the error is raised from `DefaultFailureHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin translation of [thaussma's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484682/11625850)

```kotlin
class CustomFailureHandler(instrumentation: Instrumentation) : FailureHandler {
    var delegate: DefaultFailureHandler = DefaultFailureHandler(instrumentation.targetContext)

    override fun handle(error: Throwable?, viewMatcher: Matcher<View>?) {
        // Log anything you want here

        // Then delegate the error handling to the default handler which will throw an exception
        delegate.handle(error, viewMatcher)
    }
}
```